# Capture All Keyboard Input

Tags: c++, windows

First off, I know this could be used for a keylogger. I'm not going for that, I'm looking to make an application that listens for custom key combinations just to automate a few really annoying tasks.

Is there some way to capture all input from the keyboard?

Comment: If what you say is true, then you don't want to listen for all key combinations. You want to listen for specific ones. Register a hot key.

Comment: What kind of "annoying tasks" are you looking to complete? Would something like a keyboard macro solve your issues or are you wanting keyboard shortcuts that execute applications?

Comment: David has a point, if you want to capture specific input then you can create an application with an input handler to only look for certain combinations that are declared as your shortcuts for such tasks.

Comment: [This guy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/nishhotkeys01.aspx) seems to have solved your problem.

Comment: You know, Windows has this built-in already, it's called [hotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). No need to hook on keyboard input.

Comment: @TheCapn An example task is I often switch between several different audio outputs on my computer. Having to navigate through all the menus and select everything is a pain when a key combo based program could do it for me.

Comment: @Glenn How would listening for keyboard input help?

Comment: @David There are ways to switch devices in code, I just want to be able to press ctrl-6 or some combination to switch the device.

Comment: "just to automate a few really annoying tasks" - what are you up to?

Comment: @Ajay I've already said what in the comments. Please read through before asking.

Comment: Hmmm. I do agree with you, but a good answer demands a good question. You can edit it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [`RegisterHotKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I don't think you want to hook all keyboard input.  You simply want an app with a hidden window listening for `WM_HOTKEY`. I don't think you even need to write it yourself. There are a lots of utilities that will do it for you and let you associate system-wide hot keys with actions of your specification, e.g. [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 4):

to capture keyboard input even when your application is not focused, you need to use [windows hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WH_KEYBOARD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_keyboardhook) one. It should be implemented as a DLL to be injected into all processes. Example [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699)