# Disable keyboard but make my program still know when a key pressed

Tags: c, windows, winapi, keyboard, event-handling

I want to write a program in C that disables the entire keyboard but continues to receive inputs in my program.

I tried using `BlockInput()`, but it also blocks the mouse, and my program can't get the keyboard input.

In other words, I want to capture keyboard events and disable them before they are processed by other programs.

For example:

When I'm running my program and try to write in my browser/notepad, nothing will be shown (like the keyboard is not working), but I can still be able to write to a file what the user wrote.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible, maybe. Intercepting the Secure Attention Sequence is totally not trivial. It's pretty unclear, what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture All Keyboard Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630623/capture-all-keyboard-input)

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick replay.
@IInspectable I'm trying to disable the keyboard for the user in other apps like notepad, browser, etc..
For example, the user types in notepad "Hello World!" **nothing** will be shown and in my program console there print "Hello World"

Comment: @stark No, I want to disable the keyboard not just capture the keys.

Comment: You just repeated your question. If that question were sufficiently complete I wouldn't be asking for clarification.

Comment: @Lidorelias3 try using a low-level keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), that will (mostly) let you do what you are asking for. I say mostly, because there are certain keystrokes you can't block (like CTRL-ALT-DEL), and also because apps can use the [Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) API to receive events directly from the keyboard hardware [before keyboard hooks see them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the need to use hooks in the comments, you also need to simulate the string output to the console based on the virtual key code. And You need to detect whether the focus of the mouse is on the notepad or browser.

Here is a code sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HHOOK keyboardHook;

LRESULT __stdcall KEYHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int num[] = { 0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44 ,0x45 ,0x46 ,0x47 ,0x48 ,0x49 ,0x4A ,0x4B ,0x4C ,0x4D ,0x4E ,0x4F,
                    0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57,0x58,0x59,0x5A,0x20};
    const char *ch[] = { "A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H","I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
                     "O","P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U" ,"V","W", "X", "Y", "Z"," "};
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            HANDLE stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            DWORD written = 0;
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbdStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

            if (stdOut == NULL || stdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                cout << "error handle" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            POINT pntCurrentCursor;
            GetCursorPos(&pntCurrentCursor);
            HWND h = FindWindow("Notepad", NULL);
            HWND h2 = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Edit", NULL);
            HWND h1 = WindowFromPoint(pntCurrentCursor);            
            if(h1 == h2)
            {                                                                 
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num) / sizeof(int); i++)
                {
                    if (kbdStruct->vkCode == num[i])
                    {
                        WriteConsole(stdOut, ch[i], 1, &written, NULL);
                    }
                }
            }                    
            return 1;
        }            
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    if (!(keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KEYHookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Failed to install keyboardHook hook!" << endl;
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
}

int main()
{
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    ReleaseHook();
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

- Notepad is the test object.
- The sample contains 26 characters(A~Z) and space bar.

Debug:

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need